# Getting started with Far Manager

Tags: documentation, far-manager, help-files

I'm interested in learning [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/). Are there any walkthroughs or tutorials or feature tours out there? The F1 help system is good, but it's more of a reference than a beginners guide.

Comment: I miss a real question here. What exactly do you want to know? It's easier to help you if there's a specific problem you're facing.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm asking if there is a general getting started guide, kind of like this: http://www.trembath.co.za/mctutorial.html or this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/midnight-commander-mc-guide-powerful-text-based-file-manager-for-unix/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll try to write small getting started guide on my site
https://conemu.github.io/en/FarManager.html

Or, may be better, to transfer it content here?

Comment: Good resource. Putting it here has the benefit of being community editable so anyone with enough rep can contribute. Plus it's easy to find on Google.