# scroll both column at the same time in twin panel view mode

Tags: software-rec, file-management

which file manager software (Total Commander, xplorer², Directory Opus,...) has twin panel view mode and it can browse files in both column at the same time, simultaneously?

My purpose is to compare files and folder by using my eyes...so if I want to browse my files and my backup files (different locations) simultaneously in twin panel view mode, which is the best file manager?

Comment: curious, you want this feature because you want to compare contents?

Comment: Yes ! Sometimes I want to compare folders using my eyes instead of using a software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Getting started with Far Manager](https://superuser.com/q/436218/139371)

You can create any macro (even for Up/Down) arrows to scroll both panels simultaneously. For example, supposing both panels are visible:

For example, how to map <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow to scroll down simultaneously

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. This will start macro recording, red "R" appears in upper-left corner.
- Press <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This will scroll both panels.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (this will stop recording) and choose desired key-combo, for example <kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, whatever you want. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm combo.

Same steps for <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow. Don't forget save recorded macro, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> in panels to save changes.

Also, I recomment you to try Far Manager with [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (I'm the author of this Windows Console Emulator). ConEmu provide many functions useful with Far (and not only). For example, shell style drag-n-drop, explorer context menu on long right click, tabs for editors/panels/viewers, thumbnails/tiles in Far panels, and much more.

Comment: Thank You ! You answered my question.
I am newbie with those file manager software.
For further knowledge, my purpose is to compare files and folder by using my eyes...so if I want to browse my files and my backup files (different locations) simultaneously in twin panel view mode, which is the best file manager ?

Comment: Btw, there is possible with Far to create macro (a bit more complicated), which will select on passive panel item with same name as on active panel.

Comment: I found the solution !!
After trying software (Total Commander, xplorer², Directory Opus, XYplorer,...) and searching in the Internet, I found that XYplorer has this feature - browsing simultaneously in twin view mode and other useful feature such as folder size, auto size column. Those are built-in feature (without install extensions). Therefore, I think XYplorer is the best alternative for Windows Explorer. On the other hand, you have to pay money for this software...

@ Maximus : Thank You for your answer ! Far Manager does not fit for me because it likes Command Prompt...