# Start ConEmu with prompt at the bottom

Tags: command-line, conemu

Is it possible that when a new console window is started the command prompt and content of ConEmu is bottom aligned?

I mean, once the window is filled, ConEmu naturally becomes bottom aligned until you clear the screen, then the prompt moves to the top again.

Is there a way to always have the prompt at the bottom?

The reason I ask for this feature is because I just got an external, vertical monitor and when the console is clear, the prompt is too high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your shell (not defined in question) but not a terminal issue.

Actually, I can't understand why console users are not using [Far Manager](https://superuser.com/q/436218/139371). It behaves exactly you wish from the box.

Well, if you want to change behavior of cmd.exe you may use [ANSI sequences](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/AnsiEscapeCodes).

1) Run you shell on ConEmu startup

```
cmd /k prompt $e[9999E$p$g & title cmd
```

[image: Task configuration]

[image: Choose task for start up]

2) Enjoy

[image: Prompt at the bottom]

Comment: I don't know how Far Manager works. I don't even know how to enable it. Based on the screenshots, I thought it's a file manager plugin. Anyway, I tried `cls1.cmd` twice. Once with `@echo %e%[2J%e%[9999E` and once with `@echo \x1B[2J\x1B[9999E`. Both times the file was in my `%ConEmuBaseDir%`. I put `cmd / k cls1.cmd & doskey cls=cls1.cmd` in startup command line. I restarted ConEmu and prompt still starts at the top...

Comment: I said "REAL ESC" character! Your "\x1B" it's not a character. Also, www.farmanager.com

Comment: You may see examples in `RenameTab.cmd` and `SetProgress.cmd` files.

Comment: After looking at `RenameTab.cmd`, I found an ESC character and I copied it and placed it as instructed in cls1.cmd. Then I retried everything. It still doesn't work...

Comment: That means you doing something wrong. Recheck your actions. Show screenshots and cmd file.

Comment: Answer updated, more easier way described.